# How do I programmatically get the credential object for Google Drive API in Xamarin Forms (no token.json file exists)?

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, google-drive-api, authorize

I need to get the credential of Google Drive API inside my mobile app to create a simple folder and upload a single file on logged in user Google drive.

I get an error from the highlighted code (AuthorizeAsync function call) when I try to implement it using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2022.

The highlighted code fails because of FileDataStore function parameter when tested on a android tablet running API 24. In ideal situation (such as this code running on desktop app), the file token.json would have been created automatically if it does not exists. But when implemented in Xamarin Forms (used for mobile app development), it gives an error, whether the file exists in the allowed mobile folder path and it also gives an error if the file does not exists in the allowed mobile folder path. It never ever creates the file on its own, the way it does in desktop app. Here is the code:

```cs
//credjson is client id info in json format read from the downloadeded credentials.json 
//I created via google cloud api enable
public static void DriveCreateFolder(string credjson)
        {
            try
            {
                
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credjson);
                UserCredential credential;

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
                {
                    string localPath = 
                    System.Environment.GetFolderPath( 
                          Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData );
                    string credPath = Path.Combine(localPath, "token.json");
                    

                                     

                    // ***THIS LINE THROWS AN ERROR BECAUSE OF FILE DATA STORE PARAMETER TOKEN.JSON***   
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                         GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);

                    
                }

                // Create Drive API service.
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName
                });

                // File metadata
                var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
                {
                    Name = "MyAppFolder",
                    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
                };

                // Create a new folder on drive.
                var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
                request.Fields = "id";
                var file = request.Execute();
                // Prints the created folder id.
                Console.WriteLine("Folder ID: " + file.Id);
                ApplicationFolder = file; 

                // return file.Id;
            }
           
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
                if (e is AggregateException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential Not found");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            //return null;
        }
```

Here are the test code, test errors I receive
Errors thrown in three different test cases:

Test Code 1:
string credPath = Path.Combine("token.json");

```
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath,     true)).Result;

Test Result 1:
AuthorizeAsync line throws an error

System.IO.IOException: 'Read-only file system'
```

Test Code 2:
string localPath =  System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string credPath = Path.Combine(localPath, "token.json");

```
                //ensure file does not exists
                if (File.Exists(credPath))
                    File.Delete(credPath);

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath,     true)).Result;

Test Result 2:
note: the packagename is not revealed on purpose in test result

credPath evaluates to "/data/user/0/mypackagename/files/.local/share/token.json"
First time when I run the code, it deletes the existing token.json and throws an error without any details. StackTrack points to “External code”.

Second time when I run the same code, the file does not exists any more and the following error shows up

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Cannot find the specified file'
```

Test Code 3:
//ensure file exists this time
if (!File.Exists(credPath))
File.Create(credPath);

```
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

        Test Result 3:
        note: the packagename is not revealed on purpose in test result

        The File.Create line throws an exception    
        System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path '/data/user/0/mypackagename/files/.local/share/token.json' is denied.'
```

Test Code 4:
string localPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string credPath = Path.Combine(localPath, "token.json");

```
                //ensure file exists
                if (!File.Exists(credPath))
                    File.Create(credPath);

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

                
    Test Result 4:
    note: the packagename is not revealed on purpose in test result

    credPath evaluates to "/data
    /user/0/mypackagename/files/.config/token.json"
    File gets created successfully this time
    AuthorizeAsync line throws the error

    System.IO.IOException: 'The file '/data/user/0/mypackagename/files/.config/token.json' already exists.'
```

Comment: Where did you actually put the file?

Comment: I did not put any file at any location as such. I just specified the folder pointed by Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData, where token.json should be created. Drive API is expected to create the file automatically. If I do not specify the path, then it throws the error that the system is read only. The function throws the error, that no such file exists. In which case I then wrote two lines of code to create an empty token.json file in the same folder for testing purpose. But then the function threw an error saying, the file already exists.

Comment: What path does `LocalApplicationData` resolve to?

Comment: It resolves to internal app storage share folder

Comment: Include in question the exact error message you get in both situations.

Comment: I have appended the exact error messages I receive in four different test cases in my edited question